# mysqli_query + foreach works differently in local and server

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, localhost

I wonder if this proceeding is correct or not, but it worked for me most of times (until now).

When I want to obtain SQL table information, I used to use the following code:

```
if (!$db = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,NAME)) return false;

$results = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `table`");

foreach ($results as $result) {
    var_dump($result);
}
```

The thing is that I test this in localhost and it works perfectly, I have the result I expected (in var_dump expected format). However, same code and same query to same database (but in server) returns a certain number of NULLs (explicitly "NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL ").

localhost: mysqli - Client API library version: 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: e707c415db32080b3752b232487a435ee0372157 $ (from phpinfo)

server: mysqli - Client API library version: 5.5.35

Question: does anyone know if this has something to do with my problem?

I would thank any kind of help. Regards!

Comment: The database tables and column ids are exactly the same?

Comment: you have to verify also php and mysql library version be the same, both in local and remote.?

Comment: try to use `print_r($result)`. it will give u all field data.

Comment: PHP Version:
Local - PHP Version 5.4.12
Server - PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11

Regarding to mysql library version, I think it does not matter, as I am using mysqli instead of mysql.

Rajlaksh, I tried that before posting here. I expected it would give me all field data, but it didn't. This is freaking me out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on both:

```
while( $row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ){
    print_r($row);
}
```

And let us know if there is still some differences.

Comment: It worked on both! No difference between both if I use the print_r function. If I use var_dump function, it looks "nice" in local and raw in server, but it doesn't matter at all. Thanks!!

Comment: Notice: I updated PHP Version from '5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11' to '5.4.30-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1' and now it works also with foreach method. :)